# ISO-8859-1Q in attached file

Tags: email, outlook, business-objects

I have a problem with attached file attached in outlook email sent by the console business objects,
his name was prefexé ISO-8859-1Q which causes me a problem opening it.
Need help to evolve. thank you

Comment: What is the error?  Please give us more details of what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Filename attribute of the Content-Disposition MIME header included an invalid charset value.

How exactly is the message created and received?

Comment: the file is a pdf file, but when I receive I am unable to open it in
outloock
Here is the message that appears is : You sould only open attachments from trustworrthy source.....

Comment: Is this a development question? "You should only open attachments from trustworthy source" is a prompt, so if you click yes, Outlook should open it.